# ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Tags: oracle12c

I am building a SQL query in Java and ending up with

```
INSERT INTO authorizations (id, typeid, s) 
  VALUES (HEXTORAW('1a225e19-8893-4068-958c-3d9914a34ca5'),
          HEXTORAW('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'), 
          '1');
```

I am getting a `ORA-01465 error`.  What is my dumb mistake I am doing?

Comment: See if this helps - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01465.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hyphens...

```
INSERT INTO authorizations (user_id, source_id, access_level) VALUES (HEXTORAW('1a225e1988934068958c3d9914a34ca5'), HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000000'), '1');
```